# How to execute a Cucumber Scenario / Feature multiple times?

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I would like to know if it is possible to execute using `cucumber-jvm` a scenario / feature multiple times. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show how you are currently executing (once).

Comment: But why would you want to run the **same** feature more than once? Di you actually want to run scenarios that are *similar* but not exactly the *same*?

Answer (score 3):

Your can use several approaches:

1. On operation system level: run command several times or write
   appropriate shell script.
2. On Cucumber level. E.g. you have
   following feature file:

`Feature: My great feature
  Scenario: My scenario
   Given My given step one
   When My when step two
   Then My then step three`

You can force cucumber-jvm run it several times e.g. 3 by transforming "Scenario" to "Scenario outlines" and using "Examples":

```
Feature: My great feature
  Scenario **Outline**: My scenario
   Given My given step <number>
   When My when step two
   Then My then step three
Examples: to run this scenario several times
   |number|
   |one|
   |one|
   |one|
```

It looks some artificially, but works.
I use this approach to gather statistics for complex tests dependent of a lot of conditions.